# Firebase Custom Domain: What happen to old domain after that?

Tags: firebase-hosting

When I just started exploring Firebase, I referenced many of the assets hosted on it, such as JavaScript files, images, and CSS from my **production site**. Now I realized that I should create a **Custom Domain** for my Firebase hosting site if I were to turn it into an official app eventually. But my concern is: Will all the links on my production site become **broken**? For example, images no longer load, JS no longer work etc.? Will Firebase auto-redirect to `https://new-subdomain.mycompany.com/images/thumbnails.png` when referencing it with:

```
<img src="https://my-id.firebaseapp.com/images/thumbnails.png" alt="thumbnail" />
```

Fixing the URLs to these assets will be very tedious because I have too many of it. Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my-id.firebaseapp.com` will continue to work just as it did before even if you add `new-subdomain.mycompany.com` as a custom domain to the `my-id.firebaseapp.com` Firebase project.